# Android: Is this just a custom ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Feed in **Four Square** android app looks like this:

[image]

A rectangular box with actual post, below which is a Text like **10 people like this** and so on.

Is this just a listView with Actual content having margins and a different background, and TextViews below it.

Because when i had a complicated ListView with an ImageView and 5-6 TextViews, it takes lot of time to load the UI.

1 of my friends who work on iOs said **Instead of Custom ListView Items, use ImageView which look like a Custom View with images and textviews. Which makes loading lot faster. But ofcourse it takes lot to implement such thing.**

*I just want to know, if its just another custom listview?*

*And that my delay to load the UI is because of someother reason?*

*Such techniques are available in android too??*

Thank You

Comment: It's a normal ListView. The magic happens at the Adapter, where all the views are inflated programatically instead of being inflated via XML. They take the response and inflate it one way or another, depending on the type of the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a `ListView` with complicated children views. Could also be an [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

There's a few reasons why it may load faster than something you've used before:

1. The images were probably already cached on the file system, so it loads from local storage rather than downloading the image.
2. The images were already the correct dimensions, so no resizing was needed.
3. Image loading was done on a background thread as to not lag the UI while images were being loaded into memory.

Comment: Its definitely not an **ExpandableListView**. Click on the Item or child open a different screen

Comment: You could force it so that it's expanded by default. You could also force it so it can't be closed. Though I will say I don't see how the performance would matter if you used an ExpandableListView over a plain ole ListView.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc I added some possible explanations as to why it may load faster than what you've experienced on your own projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could expand a complex layout for each ListView item in Adapter.getView() and remove (View.setVisibility(View.Gone)) on the views you don't need based on the item's object you want to render.

If you want to reuse the expanded layout don't forget to set the visibility of everithing again to View.VISIBLE.

I'm already doing this in my code:

```
        if (post.getImageURL() != null && !post.getImageURL().isEmpty()) {
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

            displayImage(post.getImageURL(), holder.image);
        } else {
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

In this case I'm hidding an optional image.